# Как правильно остановить ServerSocket без исключений?

Tags: java, многопоточность, сервер

Как остановить `ServerSocket` без выбрасывания исключений?

Код сервера:

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Server {

        private BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        private static ExecutorService executeIt = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        private Socket client;


        public static void main (String [] args) {
            Server server = new Server();
            server.go();
        }

        public void go () {

            try {               
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket (3345);

                Thread t = new Thread (new ServerCheck(server)) ;
                t.start();

                System.out.println("connection accepted");
                System.out.println("DataInputStream and DataOutputStream created");

                while (!server.isClosed()) { 

                    System.out.println("Server reading from channel");                
                    client = server.accept();
                    executeIt.execute(new MonoThreadClientHandler(client));
                    System.out.println("Connection accepted."); 
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }


    public class ServerCheck implements Runnable  {
        ServerSocket sc;
        public ServerCheck (ServerSocket sc) {
        this.sc=sc;
    }            
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (br.readLine().equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
                br.close();
                sc.close();                
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

}
```

При выполнении `ServerSocket.close()` вылетает исключение:

> java.net.SocketException: socket closed

в строке:

```
client = server.accept();
```

Как я понимаю, на этой строке поток останавливается и джем коннекта от клиента.

Как правильно обойти это исключение и завершить работу сервера?

Comment: Используйте стандартный механизм остановки сервера, `ServerSocket.accept()` блокирует поток, поэтому надо запускать сервер в отдельном неблокирующем потоке.

Comment: А можно чутка поподробнее?